# How to use $stateParams ionic

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm developing an app where it uses the information of the first page so that, that information is used as the input for the second page. To pass the information I'm using the `$stateParams` but still, the second page didn't display the output.

html page 1:

```
<ion-list>
  <ion-item ng-model="carBrand" ng-repeat="name in carSelect"  ng-click="selectItem(carBrand)">
      {{name.name}}
  </ion-item>
 </ion-list>
```

html page 2:

```
<ion-checkbox ng-model="cartype" ng-repeat="brandType in carBrand.types">
   <div align="center"><span>{{brandType}}</span></div>
</ion-checkbox><br><br>
```

controller:

```
carService.controller('carBrand',['$scope','carRepository','$rootScope','$state','$stateParams',function($scope,carRepository,$rootScope,$state,$stateParams){

 $scope.newCarList=[];
 $rootScope.carSelect=carRepository.data;
 $scope.selectItem=$stateParams.name;
 $scope.selectItem=function(key){

 $scope.newCarList.push(key);
 $state.go('app.CarDetails',{value:$scope.name});
}
```

app.js

```
var carService = angular.module('CarWash',['ionic']).config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  $stateProvider
    .state('app.Cartype',{
        url:'/Cartype',
        views:{
          'menuContent':{
            templateUrl:'templates/Cartype.html',
            controller:'carBrand'
          }
        }
      })
      //carEdit.html

    .state('app.carEdit',{
        url:'/carEdit',
        views:{
          'menuContent':{
            templateUrl:'templates/carEdit.html'
          }
        }
      })
```

Comment: What do your routes look like?

Comment: @Makoto I have edited the post. hope this helps

Comment: why do you set `$scope.selectItem = $stateParams.name` and then the next line you define it as a function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're using UIRouter as well?

There are 2 glaring issues I see right away.

- you're telling UIRouter to go to a state 'app.CarDetails' which I don't see defined in your $state config
- you haven't declared any params to use in your states.

When you want to drive a UI state with parameters, you need to either define the params in the URL or define a params object on the state.  Let's assume that you wanted to go to 'app.CarEdit' when you click the item.  Your state would look like this:

**URL driven parameters:**

```
.state('app.CarEdit', {
    url: '/edit/{type}',
    ....
})
```

**OR**

**hash-driven parameters:**

```
 .state('app.CarEdit', {
     url: 'carEdit',
     params: { type: undefined }
 })
```

In either case when you call `$state.go` you need to pass the params back with `type` defined:

```
$state.go('app.CarEdit', { type: $scope.selectedType })
```

Something like that.